# One upvote + accepted answer = 110 reputation points?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, bounties

I like reputation points as much as anyone else, but I am curious as to how this happened. The answer was quickly accepted so that should out-rule a bounty.

Is this a bug? I noticed the gain in my actual reputation points as well.

Here's a link to the question: *[Edit first column of GridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2599352/2603075#2603075)*

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is no longer relevant, as an outlined checkmark is no longer used to denote bounties.

Comment: @SonictheWizardWerehog If the question gets closed for a custom reason, it will be marked as "has nothing to do with Stack Exchange", so it's better to not use custom reasons unless you really have to.

Comment: @DonaldDuck I'm aware of that; it takes just two close voters to override that. I use them as a strategic move so it's clear to close voters and future readers why that close reason applies, fully trusting that others will pick the right choice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer has a yellow border.

That tells you it's a bounty accepted answer.

Comment: How did he assign a bounty to his question without waiting the two days?

Comment: @rlb What do you mean? it was asked on April 8th

Comment: And it was answered shortly after - you can't assign a bounty right away on a new question, you have to wait three days?

Comment: The bounty was placed after 2 days, and it was awarded to your answer manually. Manual acceptance can be done on **any** answer. You are thinking about the rules for auto acceptance.

Comment: The answer was only accepted recently. Hence, he probably posted a bounty to see if he could get any better answers, and when none showed up, yours became accepted. And you reap the bounty.

Comment: Thanks! (I can accept this answer in 8 minutes 15 characters)

Comment: @rlb just so we're clear -- you must wait 2 days before starting a bounty, and you must wait 1 day after starting a bounty. So 3 days is as fast as it can possibly be done, ever.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there was a bounty on the question -- outlined check mark.